# Prove that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all real numbers $x_1,x_2....x_n \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and for all real numbers $x_1,x_2....x_n \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$|x_1 + x_2 +....+x_n| \leq |x_1| + |x_2| +...+|x_n|$$

My attempt:

Base case: $n = 1$

$$|x_1| \leq |x_1|$$

Induction step: $n + 1$

$$|x_1 + x_{n+1}| \leq |x_1| + |x_{n+1}|$$

By the triangle inequality we have shown the inequality to be true for $n + 1$

Is this a valid and good proof? Is there something I am missing or should add?

Comment: Do you mean $|x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n|$ instead of $|x_1,x_2...x_n|$?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães Ah yes, thanks for pointing that out. Editing now.

Answer (score 2):

Induction step, If the statement holds for $n$, then it is to be shown that it holds for $n+1$. That is, the following should be shown to be true

$$
|x_1+\dots x_n| \leq |x_1|+\dots |x_n| \overset{by\ triangle\ inequality}{\Longrightarrow} |x_1+\dots +x_{n+1}| \leq |x_1|+\dots |x_{n+1}|
$$
That's how it goes
$$
(\text{by triangle inequality})\ |x_1+\dots +x_n+x_{n+1}| \leq |x_1+\dots+x_n|+|x_{n+1}| \\
(\text{by the assumption for } n)\Rightarrow |x_1+\dots +x_{n+1}| \leq |x_1|+\dots +|x_n|+|x_{n+1}|
$$

Comment: Ok, thank you. And how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Did I not do that already when I stated the triangle inequality?

Comment: If that what you meant

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

For $ n=1$, it is obvious.

For $ n=2 $, we prove by disjunction of cases that
$$|x_1+x_2|\le |x_1|+|x_2|$$

for the $(n+1)^{\text{th}}$ step, you have to check that
$$|x_1+x_2+...+x_n+x_{n+1}|\le$$
$$|x_1|+|x_2|+...|x_n|+|x_{n+1}|$$

Comment: Ok and did I not show that by stating the triangle inequality definition?

Answer (score 1):

To do a proof by induction you need to assume that the statement is true for $n$ and then show it holds for $n + 1$. One way is the following:

Let's assume that $|x_1 + ... + x_n| \leq |x_1|+ ... + |x_n|$

Then $|\underbrace{x_1 + ... + x_n}_k + x_{n + 1}| \leq |k| + |x_{n + 1}|$. This is just the triangle inequality. But $|k |\leq |x_1|+ ... + |x_n|$. So this means that:

$$|\underbrace{x_1 + ... + x_n}_k + x_{n + 1}| \leq |k| + |x_{n + 1}|\leq |x_1|+ ... + |x_n| + |x_{n + 1}|$$

You know it's true for $n = 2$ and here you have it

Answer (score 1):

To show the inductive step I would use your idea of triangle inequality:

$$
|x_1+\dots +x_n| \leq |x_1|+\dots |x_n| \implies |x_1+\dots+ x_n| +|x_{n+1}| \leq |x_1|+\dots +|x_n|+|x_{n+1}| $$

but by triangle inequality $ |x_1+\dots x_n+x_{n+1}| \leq|x_1+\dots x_n|+|x_{n+1}|$.